Asymptotics cosine integral
I’m working on the following integral:
$$
I(m) = \int_0^\pi \cos(mt) (1 - \cos t)^s \, dt, \quad m \in \mathbb{N},
$$
and I’m interested in finding its asymptotics as $ m \to \infty $.
My first approach was to do a change of variables, so the integral becomes:
$$
I(m) = \frac{1}{m} \int_0^{m\pi} \cos(u) \left(1 - \cos \left(\frac{u}{m}\right)\right)^s \, du.
$$
Using the approximation $ 1 - \cos(t) \approx \frac{t^2}{2} + O(t^4) $ for small $ t $, I obtained:
$$
I(m) \approx \frac{1}{m^{1+2s}} \int_0^{m\pi} \cos(u) \left(1 + O\left(\frac{u^2}{m^2}\right)\right)^s \, du.
$$
However, I’m now stuck on how to estimate this integral. I’ve looked into asymptotic methods like stationary phase, and I understand I can treat the cosine as the real part of a complex exponential, but I’m not sure how to apply that here.
Any suggestions or guidance on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated!

Let's denote
$$J(m) =\frac{1}{m} \int_0^{m\pi} e^{iu} \left(1 - \cos \left(\frac{u}{m}\right)\right)^s du$$
then the desired integral
$$I(m)=\Re J(m)$$
Now, let's go in the complex plane and consider the quarter-circle closed contour with the radius $R=m\pi: \,\,0\to m\pi\to m\pi e^{\frac{\pi i}2}\to 0$. We do not have singularities inside the contour; therefore
$$J(m)+I_{C_R}+\frac1m\int_{m\pi}^0e^{-u}\left(1-\cos \left(\frac{iu}{m}\right)\right)^s idu=0$$
where $I_{C_R}$ denotes the integral along the big arch of our quarter-circle. Integrating by parts
$$I_{C_R}=\frac{\pi m}m\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{\pi ime^{i\phi}}\left(1-\cos \left(\frac{\pi me^{i\phi}}{m}\right)\right)^sie^{i\phi}d\phi$$
$$=\pi\int_1^ie^{\pi imz}\left(1-\cos \pi z\right)^sdz$$
$$=\frac1{im}e^{\pi imz}\left(1-\cos \pi z\right)^s\,\bigg|_{z=1}^{z=i}-\frac {\pi s}{im}\int_1^ie^{\pi imz}\left(1-\cos \pi z\right)^{s-1}\sin\pi z\,dz$$
Integrating by parts step by step, on the upper bound ($z=i$) we get exponentially small terms ($\sim e^{-\pi m}$), so we have to consider only $z=1$. But on the lower bound the terms appear to be equal zero - when we take the real part (due to the combination $\sin u\cdot\sin(mu)$). It means
$$\Re\, I_{C_R}\sim e^{-\pi m}$$
and can be dropped. Therefore,
$$I(m)\sim\Re\frac1m\int_0^{\pi m}e^{-u}\left(1-\cosh\left(\frac um\right)\right)^sidu=\Re\frac1m\int_0^{\pi m}e^{-u}\left(\cosh\left(\frac um\right)-1\right)^se^{\frac{\pi i}2+\pi is}du$$
$$I(m)\sim-\,\frac{\sin\pi s}m\int_0^{\pi m}e^{-u}\left(\cosh\left(\frac um\right)-1\right)^sdu\tag{1}$$
Decomposing the integrand in the powers of $\frac um$ and expanding integration to $\infty$
$$I(m)\sim-\,\frac{\sin\pi s}{2^sm}\int_0^\infty e^{-u}\left(\frac um\right)^{2s}du=-\,\frac{\sin\pi s}{2^sm^{1+2s}}\Gamma(1+2s)$$
Next asymptotic terms can also be found from the formula (1).

Wow, amazing proof, thanks!
There's one thing that I don't really get, when working on the integral $I_{C_R}$ in the last paragraph you say that integrating by parts step by step, what do you mean, integrating by parts as many times as you need?
And one more comment, when in (1) you take out the $-1$ from $1-\cosh\frac{u}{m}$, we can do it as one is a real number and the other one is purely negative? I mean I have seen a lot of paradoxes where this don't work haha.
Thanks again!

Regarding $I_{C_R}$: we integrate along the arch: $dx=\pi me^{i\phi}id\phi=\pi mdz;,z=e^{i\phi}$. As $\phi\in[0;\pi/2];, z\in[1;i]$. And then $e^{\pi imz}dz=\frac1{i\pi m}d(e^{\pi imz})$. Regarding $(1-\cosh\frac um)^s$ - there is the only way to assign the meaning to this expression: we integrate counter-clockwise, in the positive direction, It means $(1-\cosh\frac um)^s=\big((\cosh\frac um-1)e^{\pi i}\big)^s=e^{\pi is}\big(\cosh\frac um-1)^s$

Maybe I explained myself badly. When you use integration by parts, how do you estimate the real part of the next integral that appears?

$$\pi\int_1^ie^{\pi imz}\left(1-\cos \pi z\right)^sdz=\frac1{im}e^{\pi imz}\left(1-\cos \pi z\right)^s,\bigg|_{z=1}^{z=i}-\frac {\pi s}{im}\int_1^ie^{\pi imz}\left(1-\cos \pi z\right)^{s-1}\sin\pi z,dz$$
$$=\frac{ie^{\pi im}}m2^s+O(e^{-\pi m})+\frac s{(im)^2}e^{\pi imz}(1-\cos \pi z)^{s-1}\sin\pi z\bigg|_1^i$$
$$+\frac s{(im)^2}\int_1^ie^{\pi imz}\big((1-\cos \pi z)^{s-1}\sin\pi z\big)'_z,dz,, \text{...etc.}$$

For every remaining integrand $,\Re f(z)<|f(z)|$ and $|f(z)g(z)|<|f(z)|\cdot|g(z)|$. As $\Im z>1$
$$|e^{\pi imz}g(z)|<|g(z)|\sim O(1)$$

The issue with that reasoning is that I don't see why the derivatives should be bounded, especially since $s$ could be less than $1$. I’ve considered the following approach: use the change of variables $z = t i + (1 - t)$ and bound the modulus of the integral. For the cosine, I’ve used the identity $ \cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$. What do you think?

Many ways lead to the goal :) For example: $1-\cos\pi z$ is equal to zero at $z=2\pi k, ,k=0;\pm 1, \pm2...$, but this is not the case if $z=e^{i\phi}, ,\phi \in[0;1]$. It means that the integrand after integration by parts $n$ times remains bounded (and is the function $\sim O(1)$)
